# Split multiple sheets excel file by one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For an example excel file `students_data.xlsx` which have 3 sheets: `students_name`, `students_score` and `students_age`

**students_name**:

```
   id class  name
0   1     a  jack
1   2     a  lucy
2   3     b   joe
3   4     b  even
4   5     b    ho
```

**students_score**

```
   id class  score
0   1     a     66
1   2     a     77
2   3     b     87
3   4     b     60
4   5     b     90
```

**students_age**

```
   id class  age
0   1     a   15
1   2     a   14
2   3     b   13
3   4     b   12
4   5     b   14
```

I have splitted each sheet to different classes using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("students_data.xlsx", sheet_name="students_name")
for i, g in df.groupby("class"):
    g.to_excel("students_name/{}.xlsx".format(i), index=False, index_label=False)
df = pd.read_excel("students_data.xlsx", sheet_name="students_score")
for i, g in df.groupby("class"):
    g.to_excel("students_score/{}.xlsx".format(i), index=False, index_label=False)
df = pd.read_excel("students_data.xlsx", sheet_name="students_age")
for i, g in df.groupby("class"):
    g.to_excel("students_age/{}.xlsx".format(i), index=False, index_label=False)
```

But I want to split by `class` with same schema for each excel file, for example, for `a.xlsx`, it will have 3 same sheets with original file but only data in `class` equals to `a`.

The final `a.xlxs` will have the following sheets:

**students_name**:

```
   id class  name
0   1     a  jack
1   2     a  lucy
```

**students_score**

```
   id class  score
0   1     a     66
1   2     a     77
```

**students_age**

```
   id class  age
0   1     a   15
1   2     a   14
```

The `b.xlsx` will look like `a.xlsx`, but only `class` euquals to `b` data contains.

How can I split and save excel files correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create dictionary of all DataFrames by `sheet_name=None` parameter.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('students_data.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

Then get all possible class by extract values of column `class`, flatten and convert to set.

```
c = set([y for k, v  in dfs.items() for y in v['class']])
print (c)
{'a', 'b'}
```

Last loop each value of set, create new `file`, filter and create all sheetnames of filtered rows:

```
for i in c:
    with pd.ExcelWriter("students_score/{}.xlsx".format(i)) as writer:
        for k, v in dfs.items():
            v[v['class'] == i].to_excel(writer, index=False, index_label=False, sheet_name=k)
```